# fread() assigns all columns classes to character even specified

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I attached my dataset below. I try to read it in `r` using `fread`. But the column classes are all `character` even I have specified them.

```
class <- c("character", "character", "numeric", "numeric","numeric", 
"character", "numeric", "numeric", rep("chracter", 5), "numeric",                                    
"chracter", "character", "factor", "character",    
"character", "character", "character", "character", "factor",                                          
"numeric", "numeric", "character",rep("numeric", 6), "character",                                      
"numeric", "factor", rep("numeric", 9) , "character", "numeric",                                       
"character", "character", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "factor",                                   
"factor", "numeric", "numeric", "factor", rep("numeric", 55))

data_q1 <- fread("LoanStats_2016Q1.csv", header = TRUE, skip = 1, nrows = 133887,  colClasses = class, fill = TRUE)

str(data_q1)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  133887 obs. of  111 variables:
 $ id                            : chr  "75577129" "75669195" "75769072" "75991583" ...
 $ member_id                     : chr  "81011841" "81136933" "81236807" "81482303" ...
 $ loan_amnt                     : chr  "25000" "4000" "3600" "8000" ...
 $ funded_amnt                   : chr  "25000" "4000" "3600" "8000" ...
 $ funded_amnt_inv               : chr  "25000" "4000" "3600" "8000" ...
```

I have check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693094/all-columns-as-character-after-importing-data-with-fread) and I tried this:

```
any(is.na(data_q1[, loan_amnt]))
[1] FALSE
```

My `loan_amnt` column does not contain `NA` values. Now I don't know what the problem is.

[data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m1vf40qaduvjgpo/LoanStats_2016Q1.csv?dl=0)

Comment: I think you are running into this problem from the doc: `fread will only promote a column to a higher type if colClasses requests it. It won’t downgrade a column to a lower type since NAs would result. You have to coerce such columns afterwards yourself, if you really require data loss.`

Comment: but the problem is the loan_amnt column does not have NA values

Comment: It could be there are no `NA` values but the data set includes other types of values for `NA`  Without having the data it's hard to know from this end.  I would visually look at all the data to see if missing values are identified as something else.

Comment: Illustrating the case Amstell described: `fread(input="col\n2\n3\n'a'", colClasses="numeric")`. Sure, there are no NAs in the result, but NAs would have been introduced by listening to `colClasses`, so it wasn't done. Try browsing your data like `data_q1[is.na(as.numeric(loan_amt))]` to see where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spelling mistake in the class vector. rep("chracter", 5) should be rep("character", 5) and this mistake is done again in the same vector